# CSS in admin-columns, Woocommerce/Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, administration

I have styled an admin-column in woocommerce. Works fine.
However, I would like to style with difference for:

1: processing order
2: completed order

The mark for each level is a 
It's in a table and comes like this:

order-status areaHere it tells the differencecompleted or processing

How do I how can i differentiate with two td/cells closed and the mark in between?

I could be a lousy explanation, English is not my main language, I am willing to try harder if you ask :o)

Thanks a lot in advance

Tried with ordinary css for the td, followed by ~ and + - nothing worked for me

EDIT: an image of my 'problem' here: I want different colors in 'completed' and 'processing'[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OshB.png)